# How to run service repeatedly even the app is closed so that it can notify the user about something through notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm making an app which shows us that which subject is being taught in classroom. I want to make a service which will run forever in background so that it can notify the user through notification even the app is closed. I tried with started activity but the service was killed after app was closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a sticky service. Here is an example. What you need is the `return START_STICKY;`.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

This service will restart when the app is closed. Meaning it will run forever.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct so that it is closed.